# Upload/Send file to Facebook via Send Api Reference

Tags: java, facebook, curl, spring-boot

Here is the curl From Facebook Docs to Upload a file to their servers for sending to the specified user:

```
curl  \
  -F recipient='{"id":"USER_ID"}' \
  -F message='{"attachment":{"type":"file", "payload":{}}}' \
  -F filedata=@/tmp/receipt.pdf \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"


curl  \
  -F 'recipient={"id":"USER_ID"}' \
  -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"audio", "payload":{}}}' \
  -F 'filedata=@/tmp/clip.mp3;type=audio/mp3' \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

I am able to do this via Curl but I would like to do that using Java and Spring-Boot.
How to go about it?

The file I am trying to send is in my src-main-resource-docs folder.

**Edit 1**
I wanted to know what's this filedata=@/tmp/clip.mp3;type=audio/MP3
Should this just be the link to my resource file?

Or do I have to change it to MultipartFile to send it?

**Edit 2**
Currently this is what I am doing:

```
  CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN");
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.addTextBody("recipient", "{"id":"USER_ID"}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);


        File f = new File("./src/main/resources/docs/test.pdf");
        builder.addBinaryBody(
            "file",
            new FileInputStream(f),
            ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
            f.getName()
        );

        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

This works fine for pdfs

But in audio/mp3 there is a type=audio/mp3 . Where do I put that?

Comment: You read the Java documentation on how to make a HTTP call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally was able to upload Docs/Media to Facebook via the Send Api Reference,here's what I did:

I used **OkHttp3** library to build the request,

```
/*
        *For Pdf ->MediaType.parse("file/pdf")
        *For Video-> MediaType.parse("video/mp4")
        *For Image-> MediaType.parse("image/png")
        */
        final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG=MediaType.parse("audio/mp3");
        final OkHttpClient client =new OkHttpClient();


        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
          .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
          .addFormDataPart("filedata", "file_name.extension", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("path_of_file")))
          .addFormDataPart("recipient","{\"id\":\"USER_ID\"}")
          .addFormDataPart("message", "{\"attachment\":{\"type\":\"TYPE_OF_FILE\", \"payload\":{}}}")//as in Facebook Docs
          .build();

      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN")
          .post(requestBody)
          .build();


      Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

      System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

One needs to add  exception handling for **IOException**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [restFb](https://restfb.com/) library. With it you will be able to do:

```
String fileName = YOUR_FILE_NAME;
byte[] fileBytes = multipartFile.getBytes(); // could be from MultipartFile, for exaple file upload from browser
String fileType = "text/csv";

BinaryAttachment binaryAttachment = BinaryAttachment.with("file", fileName, fileBytes, fileType);
// FacebookClient from the library, look in the library docs how to use it; 
// also there are several overloaded publish methods you can use
facebookClient.publish(endpoint, String.class, binaryAttachment);
```